# Using MS Graph from SharePoint Framework 1.5.1 / 1.6

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Can someone, please help me with figuring out how to use `MSGraphClient` from the latest SPFx version? `MSGraphClient` is supposed to help us to use MS Graph. My problem is that as soon as I add the line below - the web part stops rendering any content. It just shows blank space. If I press F12 - there are no errors, only warnings, but I don't know if they are relevant. I also get a ton of warnings even if webpart works fine. The only difference I can see in the console is this warning: `unreachable code after return statement[Learn More] tokenfactoryiframe_b6644a.js:formatted:5557`

```
const client:MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);
```

[image]

[image]

Procedure used to deploy SPFx web part:

- gulp bundle --ship
- gulp package-solution --ship
- move .sppkg file to the app catalog
- approve the app
- Approve permissions that the app requests in the central admin, in the **API management** page (using modern design)

I'm using "Targeted release for everyone" for the tenant.

**versions**

- npm: 6.2.0
- nodejs: 8.11.3
- sfpx (@microsoft/generator-sharepoint): 1.5.1

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "graph",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.5.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.5.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.5.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

**PeopleGraph.tsx**

```
import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-client-preview';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import * as React from 'react';
import { IPeopleGraphProps } from './IPeopleGraphProps';
import styles from './PeopleGraph.module.scss';
export default class PeopleGraph extends React.Component<IPeopleGraphProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IPeopleGraphProps> {

    // IF THIS LINE IS USED - WEB PART IS NOT RENDERED:
    // IF IT'S COMMENTED OUT - WEB PART RENDERS JUST FINE:
    const client:MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);


    return (
      <div className={ styles.peopleGraph }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Graph API test</span>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**package-solution.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "graph-client-side-solution",
    "id": "6963f50a-1c8a-4123-b5ed-9bb6c1ae23d8",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "skipFeatureDeployment": true,
    "webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Calendars.Read"
      }
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/graph.sppkg"
  }
}
```

**PeopleGraphWebPart.manifest.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json",
  "id": "39814767-90d9-4448-bd92-d20f7ae335bc",
  "alias": "PeopleGraphWebPart",
  "componentType": "WebPart",
  "version": "*",
  "manifestVersion": 2,
  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70",
    "group": { "default": "Other" },
    "title": { "default": "PeopleGraph" },
    "description": { "default": "PeopleGraph description" },
    "officeFabricIconFontName": "Page",
    "properties": {
      "description": "PeopleGraph"
    }
  }]
}
```

[image]

**Update**

- Removed node_modules
- Updates package.json to include -plusbeta
- run `npm install`
- run `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` again
- re-upploaded the .sppkg file

Results:
I had some progress! Now the browser console was throwing this error:

> Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=90bee1f7-5e6e-4d8a-9f3d-ecd601259da7&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebshell.suite.office.com%2Fiframe%2FTokenFactoryIframe&state=bb4e8feb-5ee6-472d-acbd-cfed338eae5d&client-request-id=251a4930-9313-4b10-b889-b05f0561f0b3&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.15&nonce=a714d6e5-696b-4058-bd89-5cd421b30576' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

So automatic sign-in via the iFrame didn't work. Then decided to "help" the graph by opening the URL mentioned in the error above myself. As a result the error went away, but there is still nothing rendered on the page and I have a ton of new errors now.

I'm attaching the screenshot so that you can get the idea:

[image]

**Update 2**

- Run `yo @microsoft/sharepoint --plusbeta`
- `gulp bundle --ship`
- `gulp` package-solution --ship
- deployed the package
- result: No difference. Same issue. The web part does not render.

**Update 3**
I have installed SPFx 1.6 and I have exactly the same issues. Could not make it work for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was quite stupid and the solution simple.

The problem was that I was relying on this.context. and this.context is null (does not exist) inside **react components**.

All the code I was using was meant to be used inside webpart's file.

Correct placement of the code:

```
class GraphTestWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IGraphTestWebPartProps>
// this.context exist here
```

Wrong placement:

```
class GraphTest extends React.Component<IGraphTestProps, {}>
// this.context is null here
```

All in all the issue was related my misunderstanding of SPFx. It's not related to Graph. Graph API works like a charm now. I'm really excited about finally using it.

Comment: You could pass the context from the webpart to your react component as properties and then do `this.props.context` in the component to reference it.

Comment: yes, agree. Good point!

Answer (score 7):

MSGraph is currently in preview. The necessary package for that is available only if you include the `--plusbeta` parameter during the creation of the solution when you start your yeoman generator.

So, for the existing solution, delete your `node_modules` solution, modify your `package.json` as below and run the `npm i` command again :

```
{
  "name": "graph",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.5.1-plusbeta",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Also, next time you create a SPFx solution, pass the `--plusbeta` flag as below and then create your solution:

`yo @microsoft/sharepoint --plusbeta`

Since SPFx 1.5, these changes have been added. To use the preview packages, we need to use `plusbeta` flag.

Reference - [Announcing SharePoint Framework version 1.5: new tools and a beta preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/announcing-sharepoint-framework-version-1-5-new-tools-and-a-beta-preview/)

[Use MSGraphClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph)

Comment: any luck @denis ? did you try the above changes or code ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @Gautam Sheth. And thank you for your help. I've only managed to test it about 2 hours ago. I definitely had some progress. At least I saw a new error message about an iframe and a bunch of other errors I don't yet understand. I've updated the questions with the results.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, MSGraph client is still in preview mode. I tried it in a tenant where we set Targeted release for all users and another test in a Microsoft demo tenant where it works. It is still not supported in standard tenant or targeted release for specific users. Would suggest that you check the release mode of the tenant.  Also, can you try with creating a new solution and checking that out ? These errors dont make sense as they are bunch of 404 and seem to mostly MS errors

Comment: I've double checked. I actually have "Targeted release for everyone" in the tenant settings. So that's not the issue. I've also generated the app from scratch using  `yo @microsoft/sharepoint --plusbeta`. Same difference. The webpart does not render.

Comment: ok, in that case your browser might be blocking it. In Chrome, there might be a popup image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaC3s.jpg), click on allow popups and then you will get through. Now your errors kinda make sense because the browser itself is blocking these requests

Comment: any luck @DenisMolodtsov ? i tested a simple graph client code and it works ! Wont work in standard release tenant, but works in first release (all users) tenant and the demo tenants as well :)

Comment: Hi @Gautam Sheth, I've tried one more time from scratch, but everything was the same. I can create a new VM and install everything from scratch and get a new free Dev Office 365 Tenant. Do you think that makes sense or it's an overkill? Will probably take me 1-2 hours to do. Not that big of a deal. I don't trust my dev environments or O365 tenants any longer.

Comment: If its not a big deal, you can try this on a new dev tenant with first release all users. Also, if your org is a Microsoft partner, you can create [demo tenants](https://demos.microsoft.com/Login) which will be always ahead of the usual release curve. The thing is this code works in my multiple envs but all of there are in first release or are MS tenants ! I also tried with the sp starter kit which has a lot of webparts using MS Graph client and it works perfectly fine :)

Comment: any luck @DenisMolodtsov ? I tried the sp starter kit on a fresh demo tenant and it worked right off the bat :) Also, just came to know that once we have enabled targeted release for all users, we need to wait upto 24 hours for the updates to be enabled in the tenant !

Comment: I have just tried SPFx 1.6. I have exactly the same issue. I wonder... Should I maybe setup CORS in Azure? Should I register Azure App? Is  there anything that I'm missing? I've just reinstalled npm, node, updated SPfx and recreated a hello world app from scratch. I've followed these articles very carefully: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph and http://spblog.net/post/2018/09/09/Using-PnPjs-to-send-requests-to-MS-Graph-with-SharePoint-Framework-16?utm_source=collab365&utm_medium=collab365today&utm_campaign=daily_digest